# Making an accelerometer/gyroscope in webgl

Tags: webgl

I need to make something [like this](http://jaanga.github.io/gestification/cookbook/pitch-roll-yaw/readme-reader.html) except instead of rotating it around with the mouse, you would just need to input the pitch yaw roll in a text box and it would rotate. I try to modify this but it seem to not working. Is there like any library to do this kind of stuff?

Comment: sorry the linked seem wrong here the new link [ http://jaanga.github.io/gestification/cookbook/pitch-roll-yaw/readme-reader.html ]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a library I recommend [glMatrix](http://glmatrix.net/docs/2.2.0/). You would do something like the following:

```
var q_ori = quat.create(); //holds orientation

// do stuff ...

quat.rotateY(q_ori, theta); //(accumulate a change in yaw by theta)

//finally convert to rotation matrix with mat3 or mat4.fromQuat

mat4.fromQuat(outMatrix, q_ori);

//pass this into a shader or whatever
```